# How can I fix my function definition to compute a parameter correctly?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I am trying to calculate the following function in Mathematica:

```
F0[z_, t_, R_] :=
  (BesselK[0, Sqrt[R] I] Sin[b](-Exp[R*t]+Cos[t]+R*Sin[t])) /
    (b*(-R*BesselK[0, Sqrt[R]*I]+ Sqrt[R]*I*BesselK[1, Sqrt[R]*I]))

F1[z_, t_] := 
  Im[2*I*NIntegrate[F0[z, t, R], {R, 0, 1}]] 
    /. FindRoot[Tan[b] == -R - 10^-4*b^2/b, {b, (2*1(*m*)+ 1)*Pi/2 + 10^-5}]
```

[image]

Here, `F1` is the main function in my model. `F0` is the integrand. As you might expect, the transcendental equation

```
Tan[b] == -R - (10^-4)*b^2/b
```

provides the root. and `R` is the Integral variable which also is included in the transcendental equation. `(2*m+ 1)*Pi/2 +10^-5` is a reasonable initial guess `Tan[b]`.

Here's the problem: `NIntegrate` and `FindRoot` can not be separate for `R`. I already have tried discretization for `R` integration, but It doesn't work and makes the function more difficult. So, do you have any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this one is a bit tricky. By common sense, one may expect that `NIntegrate` solely needs evaluation of the integrant at some quadrature points. But `NIntegrate` also tries to analyze the integrant symbolically leading to calls to `F0` with symbolic arguments. In out case, this is quite bad as our integrant `F0[z,t,R]` makes only sense, if `R` has a concrete numerical value; otherwise `FindRoot` will complain. I did several things with your code. First, I encapsulated solving process into the integrant `F0`. Second, I used the pattern `R_?NumericQ` in the declaration of `F0` in order to suppress evaluation of `F0[z_, t_, R]` for non-numeric `R`. This makes it working. However, I have not checked if the result is correct.

```
F0[z_, t_, R_?NumericQ] := Block[{b, b1, sol},
  sol = FindRoot[Tan[b1] == -R - 10^-4 b1, {b1, (2 + 1) Pi/2 + 10^-5}];
  b = b1 /. sol;
  (BesselK[0, Sqrt[R] I] Sin[b] (-Exp[R t] + Cos[t] + R Sin[t]))/(b (-R BesselK[0, Sqrt[R] I] + Sqrt[R] I BesselK[1, Sqrt[R] I]))
  ]

F1[z_, t_] := Im[2 I NIntegrate[F0[z, t, R], {R, 0., 1.}]]

F1[1, 1]

(* -0.0272283 *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. In addition, If I want to use the Summation with the `NIntegrate` for different  `b` that  replace `(2 + 1) Pi/2 + 10^-5` to `(2 + m) Pi/2 + 10^-5` how can I do for it ??

Comment: What is `m`? If it is a numerical number, then simply  put it at the respective place. Well, you would not ask, if it is numerical. However, if it is not, then there is no point in using `NIntegrate`...

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean. thank you !!!

Comment: You're welcome.